What did the "Turbo" button on old PCs do?
Talking 80s IBM compatibles.
When I built systems in the computer store, I never connected the turbo switch because I was afraid a naive user might accidentally push it and slow their machine down forever.
The turbo button was a handy switch when you wanted to control  other devices. Like, I turned it into a mute button for a housemate's computer.
Did "turbo" do anything other than slow the clock?
Did it actually serve a useful purpose, other than slowing down early games that ran as fast as they could? Why won't anyone want a button that didn't do anything but make their machine run slower?

Making the machine run slower to be able to run games coded for slower machines was good enough reason. Delay loops are hard to get right if you don’t have machines from the future to test on.

It was also good for making those cool 2-digit LED displays on the front panel change.  :-)

It wasn't just games.  There was peripheral hardware that sometimes wouldn't work at the faster-than-standard-PC speed - either the hardware couldn't be clocked that fast and would just fail or the software drivers had timing issues.  These could be anything from industrial/laboratory interface boards to more common office (and home) things that were not-too-common I/O devices.  (Scanners, e.g.,?)
